# Turn on pc on remotely

Tags: windows, remote-access, remote-desktop, bios, uefi

So I'm going away for holidays and I only take a Laptop with me. My plan is that I plug my PC into a smart home plug which I can control on my smartphone and if I turn on the plug I the PC should power up. After that I should be able to connect to my PC with a remote desktop application. Can someone tell me what I have to change in the BIOS to make that happen?
Btw. I have an Aorus motherboard.

Comment: Did you try the BIOS setting Search field, searching for `Power`? (On my Aorus, this field is in the upper right.) Some computers have a setting for what to do on power restoration, whether to remain off or return to the previous state.

Comment: I have a setting called "Platform Power" which is a bunch of settings combined. There is an option called  "Ac Back". Do I need to use that one?

Comment: Yes, see my answer I just posted ten seconds before you commented LOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what model of Aorus you have, but if you look at the [manual](https://download.gigabyte.com/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_x570-aorus-master_1002_e.pdf), look for "AC Back" setting under "Platform Power" (Page 48 of that PDF). Looks like this is an "Advanced" setting under the "Settings" tab.